# Typescript With Generics Property 'input' does not exist on type 'T'

Tags: node.js, typescript, generics, types

I'm using typescript 4.8,
I have an error on my types that I really don't understand.

```
function normalize<T = (InputData | Omit<InputData, "output">)>(
    company: T
): any {
    console.log(company.input.numberOfWorker);
}
```

This will show: `Property 'input' does not exist on type 'T'.`,
But input does exist on InputData.

But the thing is, if I do that it works:

```
function normalize(
    company: InputData | Omit<InputData, "output">
):any {
    console.log(company.input.numberOfWorker);
}
```

and for me that the same thing no ? since T is meant to be equal to InputData or the Omit

Thanks a lot if you can explain me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

```
<T = (InputData | Omit<InputData, "output">)>
```

This only assigns a default type to `T`. However a consumer of this function could pass in any type, which may not be the same shape as `InputData` and therefore does not have the `input` property, into the type parameter. For example:

```
normalize<string>("");
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgA4FcwBE5hzIDeAUMhcqNmAFzJwgCeA3OZQPY432OukBfUqRhYQCMMA4hkIDlAC2cADbAAXhAA8AFWQBeZAAp0NfIWQAfZAHkFwMJpM4zcADTIARFzA0PAPgBKP0N2CgQOBQw+em1SAN5mElDkcJAAZw5lCAA6ZQ4Ac0NwyL5s6hxskCwFACNoaxgAdXkAa2gAtiFSOUUVdS00sChQfOCPDw7SIA)

## Solution

You want to add a constraint to `T`. This is done using the `extends` keyword like so:

```
<T extends (InputData | Omit<InputData, "output">)>
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgA4FcwBE5hzIDeAUMhcqNmAFzJwgCeA3OZQPY432OukBfUqRhYQCMMA4hkIDlAC2cADbAAXhAA8AFWQQAHpBAATAM7IAFOhr5CyAD7IA8guBhN1nLbgAaZACIuMBp-AD4ASlCLdgoEDgUMPnptUnDeZhIY5DiQUw5lCAA6ZQ4Acws4hL5C6hxCkCwFACNoJxgAdXkAa2hwtiEgA)

## Further reading

- [TypeScript documentation on generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints)